# How to display text in top-down languages (Japanese, Chinese, etc.) on iOS and Android?

Tags: unicode, fonts, localization

How to display text in top-down languages (Japanese, Chinese, etc.) on iOS and Android?

For iOS, I've found this:
https://github.com/novi/LTCoreText
... Any other alternative for iOS?

For Android, I cannot find any library/framework. Does anyone know?

Comment: I would like to do this for Chinese on both Android and iOS. Did you ever find any solutions?

Answer (score 1):

You may use a custom view to draw text on it vertically, just like below screenshot, these are traditional Mongolian script.

```
public class DrawTextView extends View {

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

    .....
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: I would be very interested in seeing more of your source code for how you display traditional Mongolian. Have you done any more with this? The way I have done it is to do a rotation on canvas.

Answer (score -2):

Simple answer: don't. Chinese and Japanese are only written top-down in traditional books. Computer applications and websites are written left-to-right, like European languages. See for example http://www.asahi.com/ (renowned Japanese newspaper) and http://xinhuanet.com/ (renowned Chinese news agency). Even modern books in China are printed left-to-right (in Japan not yet). The only script that I know that has to be printed top-down is the [traditional Mongolian script](http://www.omniglot.com/writing/mongolian.htm) - and that doesn't matter because Mongolian is written using the Cyrillic alphabet now.

Comment: Apps which display Chinese/Japanese top-down exists. We need to develop an app to publish e-Books, to mimic the feel of those printed books which are written top-down.

Comment: Traditional Mongolian script is still used in Inner Mongolia.